# How to efficiently filter two-dimensional np array by values given in a list (by many values)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a two-dimensional np array and I need to efficiently filter it by values given in a list.

```
b = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd'], ['c', 'b', 'a', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'c', 'b']])
values_to_stay_in_b = ['a', 'b']
```

I found solution with using set difference, but the position in array b is important.

Is any better solution than simple list comprehensions as below:

```
output = []
for l in b:
    output.append([a for a in l if a in values_to_stay_in_b ])
np.array(output)
```

Result:

```
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['b', 'a'],
       ['b', 'a'],
       ['a', 'b']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Would there always be the same amount of columns per row in the output?

Comment: You will have to iterate through all values anyway. So in terms of efficiency there is not much to do I think. You could store the values_to_stay_in_b in a dictionary to make the look up time smaller. If you are looking for ways to to write it more pythonic, maybe you can use calls like `b[b=='a']`.

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes

Answer (score 0):

Using pure numpy, so atleast removing for loops.

For each entry in b, compare it with each entry in values_to_stay_in_b and get a mask list. This is done adding extra axis and comapring using broadcasting

Any one in this need to be true.

Since you clarify that after filtering each row has same columns, I reshape it based on number of rows

```
b[(b[..., None] == values_to_stay_in_b).any(axis=2)].reshape(b.shape[0], -1)
```